# AJAX Returning Contents of PHP Proxy File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my first time posting on stackoverflow, so bear with me. I'm currently building a hybrid HTML5 application for android, and I have a javascript variable that I need to pass to a server. I'm doing so by making an AJAX request and specifying a PHP file as a proxy to get around the Same-Origin policy. However, this posed a surprising problem. My AJAX get method does not return the results of my PHP file if it were to be run, but rather the file itself.

Here is the AJAX code:

```
function connect(trimmedData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'php/SOAPProxy.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(y + '\n' + z);
            console.log(y + '\n' + z);
        },
        data: { 'method': 'checkUser', 'args': { 'name': 'email', 'value': trimmedData } },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#mainpage").append("Success");
            $("#mainpage").append(data);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            $("#mainpage").append("FAILURE");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

  $client = new SoapClient("someURL");
  $m=$_GET['method'];
  if(isset($_GET['args'])){
    $result = $client->$m(array($_GET['args']['name']=>$_GET['args'] ['value']));
 }
 else{
   $result = $client->$m();
 }
 $j = json_encode($result)
 print $j;
?>
```

According to examples I've seen, this should work, but obviously that isn't the case. Can somebody give me any ideas as to where I may be going wrong?

Thanks!

Additional Info: These are all SOAP requests being run, the input is a user email, and the response is a string of some sort.

Setting datatype to "text" strangely doesn't return the entire file, but rather everything from $m(array onwards. Still trying to determine why that would be.

Comment: whan you `alert(data)` in the sucess function you get the php file?

Comment: Is php installed and enabled on that server? Try running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in an empty php file and open in browser

Comment: @madalin ivascu The PHP file is returned within the error segment. Because the AJAX request is looking for JSON data, it never actually gets to the success function.

Comment: @charlietfl I'll try that next. Unfortunately because this is a group project, I don't have access to the server right now. All I have access to are the methods I can call.

Comment: try to reach the PHP file through a browser. If you see the PHP code displayed, php on the server is not running or misconfigured. If the file is interpreted, your problem is of a different nature.

Comment: try adding a json header: `header('Content-Type: application/json')`

Comment: from php.net SoapClient class does not have any m function

Comment: @madalinivascu The header function, while a possibility, does not work. $m is a variable above that is equal to a function. However, that gives me an idea...

Comment: @madalinivascu Still nothing.

Comment: try wraping the content in a function that returns the json and than call it

Comment: @madalinivascu Same thing as before.

Comment: try usign post istead of get

Comment: @madalinivascu Tried that ages ago. It gives no data back at all.

Comment: Hi all, feel free to keep giving tips, but I believe the issue is that my partner for this project never actually enabled PHP for the server. I cannot verify it at this time, as he isn't currently awake, but that's my first guess. If that's the case, I'll close this out and feel extremely ashamed of not thinking of this sooner.

Comment: Here's an update. My previous idea doesn't seem to be the case. My partner has PHP set up properly. I can't figure out for the life of me what's causing this issue.